# Different Log4j file paths for each webapp

Tags: spring, log4j, environment

I'm trying to use different logs for each webapp. I've multiples applications in the same server and I need to load this directory from a properties file.

Each web app loads a property file with this keys/values (X it's the app's name, different for all):

```
app=APP.X
logPath=C://logs
```

I have added a log4j.properties file in each webapp project with all parameters that I need except the log's path (log4j.properties)

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c:%M:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c:%M:%L - %m%n
#log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=8
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM
```

I have created a Java class in my util jar that implements ApplicationListener and adds the key log4j.appender.file.File (Log4jContextListener.java)

```
    public class Log4jContextListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent>
{
    @Value("${rutaLogs}")
    private String rutaLogs;

    @Value("${app}")
    private String app;

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent arg0)
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream strm = null;
        try
        {
            System.out.println("LOADING APP: " + app);
            strm = Log4jContextListener.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties");
            props.load(strm);
            if (props != null)
                log.info("PROP: " + props.getProperty("log4j.appender.file.layout"));
            props.put("log4j.appender.file.File", logPath+ app + File.separator + app + ".log");
        }
        catch (IOException propsLoadIOE)
        {
            throw new Error("can't load logging config file", propsLoadIOE);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                strm.close();
            }
            catch (IOException configCloseIOE)
            {
                throw new Error("error closing logging config file", configCloseIOE);
            }
        }
        // props.put("webAppRoot", event.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"));
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);

    }

}
```

And each web app adds a bean with this declaration in the applicationContext.xml

```
<!--    Listener to initialize LOG4J -->
    <bean id="log4jConfigurationListener" class="com.framework.listeners.Log4jContextListener" />
```

The log's folders and files are creating right but the log traces are mixed, each webapp use only the latest location loaded.

How can I do diferent in each wepapp context?

PD: I have to do it reading from properties, I can't use environment vars.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I manage to set log location per webapp context with the following:

```
package ...

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.lf5.LogLevel;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class SystemPropertyDefaultsInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SystemPropertyDefaultsInitializer.class);

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    String warName = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/")).getName();

        InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties");
        Properties properties = PropertiesHelper.loadApplicationProperties(resourceAsStream);

    String logLocation = "/var/log/tomcat7/" + warName + ".log";
    File file = new File(logLocation);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.close();
    }

    if (!file.canWrite()) {
        throw new IOException("Write permission denied for file \"" + logLocation + "\"");
    }


    LOG.info("Log location set to: \"" + logLocation + "\"");
    properties.setProperty("log4j.appender.FILE.File", logLocation);
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(properties);
    }
}
```